# Inconvenientes con función for en RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Cordial saludo, agradezco por favor su colaboración con el siguiente inconveniente en la herramienta RStudio con dos for, el código es el siguiente:

install.packages("svDialogs") # Para instalar el paquete
library(svDialogs)

```
#i <- 1
#cont <- 0
for (i in 1:10){
  for (cont in 1:10){
    x <- dlgInput(message="Digite valor: ")$res
    x <- as.integer(x) 
  
    par<-x %% 2 == 0
     switch (par,
            print(x), 
            i <- i + 1,    # condicional   si es número par
            cont <- cont + 1)
  
    
}
}
```

Al correr el programa valida muy bien que imprima los números pares, pero no realiza bien el proceso de pedirme de 1 hasta 10 veces sino que lo realiza indefinidamente la petición de números.

Muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 3):

`switch()` espera un expresión que determine que siguiente parámetro evaluar, si el valor evaluado es 1, se evalúa el segundo parámetro, si es 2 el tercero, y así.

```
# Si x=1 -> "param 1"
# Si x=2 -> "param 2"
# Si x=3 -> "param 3"
switch(x, "parm 1", "param 2", "param 3")
```

Ahora si el valor es 0, no se evalúa nada (en R cualquier índice comienza por 1). Este es uno de los problemas que tienes, cuando haces `par <- x %% 2 == 0`, el resultado solo puede ser `TRUE` o `FALSE` que como numéricos son 1 y 0 respectivamente. Es decir, cuando el valor es par el `switch` hace lo que esperas, evalúa el siguiente primer parámetro, pero cuando en 0 no hace nada, por que no hay parámetro con el índice 0.

El otro problema que tienes es un tema de lógica, ¿dónde entraría `cont <- cont + 1`? así como está el código y dado que la evaluación solo da dos posibles valores, nunca se ejecutaría. Si el incremento de `cont` lo quieres ejecutar junto con el de `i` eso, junto con el problema anterior se podría resolver así:

```
switch (par + 1,
        {i <- i + 1;cont <- cont + 1},
        print(x)
)
```

Sumándole 1 a `par` convertimos el `FALSE` en 1 y el `TRUE` en 2, resta invertir los parámetros y encerrar entre llaves la evaluación de los dos incrementos.

Como comentario final, este es un caso dónde claramente el `switch()` aporta poco en relación con un `if()` tradicional:

```
if (x %% 2 == 0) {
  print(x)
} else {
  i <- i + 1
  cont <- cont + 1
}
```